# How to animate Activity-dialog size change

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, dialog

I have an Activity with the dialog theme.
At some point I want to change the content of my dialog to show a loading icon.

How can I animate the reduce of size from the original content to my new content ? I've tried using `animateLayoutChanges` on the root element of my activity but it does not work.